# XML Spy Blocks Weblogic 10.3.2

Tags: java, webserver, xml

My computer was shut down abruptly and since then I'm not able to run Weblogic (10.3.2) locally on my computer (neither from Eclipse or manually from the Oracle domain). I keep getting the message:

> \Altova\xmlspy\XMLSpyInterface.jar was unexpected at this time.

I deleted all of what is related to Xmlspy and I still get this error. any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you have installed XMLSpy with Oracle weblogic product and XMLSpy is not licensed one. Please uninstall the XMLSpy and try it